# How to pass parameters in different classes

Tags: .net, design-patterns, software-design

I have created small framework component that consist of Processes and Tasks (not .NET API classes).

Processes can contain multiple tasks.

Now within a process, there are a list of parameters that should be available to each tasks.

The requirement is
1. The tasks should come from DI
2. The list of parameters is owned from Process, and and should be available to all tasks. Task will read parameters, and can also add some parameters

Current Implementation -> Initialize method is specified in BaseTask (from which all tasks derive) and BaseProcess (from which all processes derive). This accepts the the parameter list as argument.

Is there any design pattern for such problems?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a factory for your tasks instead of actually embedding the tasks directly into the Process.  The simplest form of that would be a delegate:

```
public class Process {

  private readonly List<Func<Process, BaseTask>> TaskFactories
    = new List<Func<Process, BaseTask>>();

  public RegisterTask(Func<Process, BaseTask> taskFactory)
  {
    TaskFactories.Add(taskFactory);
  }

  public IEnumerable<Task> CreateTasks() {
    return TaskFactories.Select(f => f(this)).ToArray();
    //ToArray used to ensure all tasks created here and now.
  }

}
```

So that you can then write a task like this:

```
public class MyTask : BaseTask { 
  public MyTask(Process p) {
    /* grab parameters from process here */
  }
}
```

And then you can register this task, given a `Process p` like this:

```
public void RegisterSomeTask(Process p) {
  p.RegisterTask((process) => new MyTask(p));
}
```

This also does away with the need for the `Initialize` method, which is, in my opinion, never an ideal pattern because it's possible to have an uninitialized task which could raise errors unless your state management is absolutely bang-on.